# Local variable and Global variable with same name and how it works?

Tags: c#

Can someone please tell me the program flow and out of the given snippet.I tried this on VS and got 0 0 as output,and i want to know how this works. Thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Sample s1 = new Sample();
    s1.getdata(10, 5.4f);
    s1.displaydata();
}

class Sample
{
    int i;
    Single j;
    public void getdata(int i,Single j)
    {
        i = i;
        j = j;
    }
    public void displaydata()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + " " + j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the local variables are preferred over the class variables, the class variables are never set. Inside the `getdata` method you are setting the local (method scoped) variables to their own value. Hence, in the `displaydata` method, you are printing the default values of the integers (0).

To fix this, you can either change the names of the variables, by prefixing them for example, or use `this` to set the scope.

```
public void getdata(int i,Single j)
{
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
}
```

Comment: This is correct; however, I would recommend using properties instead of fields.  There are many advantages with little added overhead.