# Having trouble assigning variables

Tags: c#

I do not understand why the variables "currHD" and "newHD" do not get assigned inside in the if statement. I tried researching why but i couldnt find anything. Trying to learn sorry if it a stupid question.

```
class Program
{
    //varaibales
    public int currHD;
    public int newHD;
    public int abilScore;
    public int feats;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //user inut
        Console.Write("Enter creature type: ");
        string creaType = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter the creature's current CR: ");
        int currCR = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter the creature's new CR: ");
        int newCR = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //varaiables
        int currHD = 0;
        int newHD = 0;
        int abilScore;
        int feats;

        //checks creature type
        if (creaType == "abberation")
        {
            //              0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
            int[] aberr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 34 };
            currHD = aberr[currCR];
            newHD = aberr[newCR];
        }


        //gets how many abilty points and feats
        abilScore = (newHD - currHD) / 4;
        feats = (newHD - currHD) / 2;

        Console.WriteLine("Ability score points: " + abilScore);
        Console.WriteLine("New feats: " + feats);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have both class-level fields and method-level variables named `currHD` and `newHD`.  Choose one or the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local variable with same name as instance variable = unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127113/local-variable-with-same-name-as-instance-variable-unexpected-results) or [Local variable and Global variable with same name and how it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35271871/150605)

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what i need to change. I dont fully understand the difference between class level fields and method level variables, still pretty new the language.

Comment: You understand that in two locations you have declared two sets of variables with the same names, yes?  The variables inside of  `Main()` are shadowing/hiding the same-named variables (fields) outside of `Main()`.  So all you need to do is just delete one of the sets of variable declarations.  Note that if you choose to delete `Main()`'s local variables you'll also need to mark the fields outside of `Main()` as `static` (e.g. `public static int currHD;`) so they can be accessed inside of a `static` method such as `Main()`.

Comment: Thank you this has helped a lot and i understand why now. Thank you for your patience.